# mdInkRipple rippling whole mdVirtualRepeat - Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use the mdInkRipple directive on a mdVirtualRepeat but I am running into an issue where the md-ink-ripple will ripple the entire virtual repeat container. Here is my code.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container md-auto-shrink="true">
    <div md-virtual-repeat="obj in controller.data" ng-click="null" md-ink-ripple>
        <div class="key-repeated" layout="column" layout-align="center start">
            <p class="md-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">{{ obj.text }}</p>
            <p class="md-body-1">{{ obj.caption }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to introduce `md-list` as the parent of the `md-virtual-repeat-container` and make its children `md-list-item` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vKgqex)

Markup

```
<md-content layout="column">
  <md-list>
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
      <md-list-item md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item" flex="" md-ink-ripple>
        {{item}}
      </md-list-item>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
  </md-list>
</md-content>
```

Additionally, **md-ink-ripple** is there by default (and also a nice mouse over effect) if the `md-list-item` has a `ng-click` attribute - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/ezgwWa)

Markup

```
<md-content layout="column">
  <md-list>
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
      <md-list-item md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item" flex="" md-ink-ripple  ng-click="hello()">
        {{item}}
      </md-list-item>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
  </md-list>
</md-content>
```

JS

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($timeout, $scope) {
    $scope.hello = function() {
      console.log("Hello!");
    }
```

CSS

```
.virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading .repeated-item {
  height: initial;
}
```